# galois deformation ring with type is union of irreducible components

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, deformation-theory, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Notation:
$K$ finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $G_K$ absolute Galois group of $K$,
$E$ is finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (coefficient field), $O_E$ is ring of integer in $E$.

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.1877.pdf) of Toby Gee, (after lemma 2.1.3) for a given complete noetherian local $O_E$-algebra $A^\circ$ with finite residue field, and rank $n$ free $A^\circ$-module $V_{A^\circ}$ with $G_K$-action, there is a quotient $A^\tau$ of $A=A^\circ[1/p]$ such that a homomorphism $A\xrightarrow{} B$ where $B$ is a finite $E$-algebra, it factors through $A^\tau$ if and only if the Weil–Deligne representation associated to $V_B=V_{A^\circ}\otimes B$ has type $\tau$ (i.e. $\tau$ is representation of $I_K$ on $E$-vector space with open kernel, and $I_K$-action on the Weil-Deligne representation associated to $V_B$ is isomorphic to $\tau\otimes B$)

He adds that $A^\tau$ is union of irreducible components of $A$, because of the fact that the cohomology of finite group of positive degree with coefficients in characteristic 0 vanishes.

I want to understand this part, and I also tried to look at [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2008-21-02/S0894-0347-07-00576-0/S0894-0347-07-00576-0.pdf) of Kisin, which Toby Gee was following closely. He proved analogous result in theorem 2.7.6, and refer subsection 2.7 to argue that the trace of elements in $I_K$ is locally constant on $\operatorname{Spec}A$.

I interpret this as Zariski locally (or étale locally?) the trace of $I_K$ is valued in some finite extension of $E$ and so the action of $I_K$ comes from a representation on $E'$-vector space.

What I don't understand about subsection 2.7 in Kisin's paper is the existence of $B'$ (we can just add necessary coefficients from $\overline{K_0}$ and it will ensure étale but why local?) and how it is used in the context of theorem 2.7.6 (does $B'$ provide étale covering of $A$? even then it is not a component in $\operatorname{Spec}A$) and why the cohomology of finite group is mentioned here.

At last, theorem 2.7.6 is using complete noetherian local $O_E$-algebra, but subsection 2.7 is using finite local $E$-algebra. I don't think this finiteness will really matter, but I would be glad if one can make this point clear.